# What causes this E474: Invalid argument error from my .vimrc?

Tags: centos, command-line, vim, vimrc

I copied my `.vimrc` from my Mac to my `~/.vimrc` on a CentOS host - it contains the following:

```
  1 set number¬
  2 set listchars=eol:¬¬
  3 set listchars+=tab:>·¬
  4 set listchars+=trail:~¬
  5 set listchars+=extends:>¬
  6 set listchars+=precedes:<¬
  7 set listchars+=space:$¬
  8 set list¬
  9 syntax on¬
```

When I try to `vi somefile` though, I get:

```
Error detected while processing /home/me/.vimrc:
line    7:
E474: Invalid argument: listchars+=space:$
```

Comment: What version of `vim` is installed on each host?  Have you tried breaking apart your `listchars` configuration to try each character one by one?

Comment: Yep, looks like the offender is `set listchars=space:·` -- I'm not sure what the equivalent could be for CentOS?

Comment: FWIW, I use `·` (U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT).  Not sure if it's the same glyph as you..

Comment: Hm, I tried just setting it to `$`, and I still get the same error. I'm not sure what's up.